# How to Override Implementation of HTTP Outbound Connector in Mule AnyPoint Studio

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component, mule-cluster

Hi I am working with a Mule Any Point Studio and I just want to know that how to configure or override HTTP Inbound/Outbound Implementation so that i can dynamically override its functionality and change it's properties like :

1. Address
2. Exchange Patterns etc

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To decide the endpoint details (such as path, host and port) dynamically i.e. at runtime, you will need to execute an expression on the current Mule message for example. See the following link section "Dynamic endpoints" for examples: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Endpoint+Configuration+Reference

Answer (score 1):

Address is configurable and can be overridden dynamically but Exchange Patterns I guess cannot be dynamically changed...
You can put the values in a properties file and and load the http inbound address dynamically  in following way :-

```
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://${host}:${port}/${path}" doc:name="HTTP"/>
```

where `${host} ${port} ${path}`  are configured in properties file

You can also do the same for outbound

Answer (score 0):

you can extend the connector nature using the service overrides concept.

can search on mule documentation for service overrides.